# angjuar - service returning $http promise instead of expected object

Tags: angularjs

I'm in the process of building my first AngularJS app and been stuck in this (supposed to be straightforward) problem.

I have a service "vehicleService" that does all $http functions. It then checks if it the operation was successful or not, then makes a new object containing the status code, and either the expected return object or the error list; which it correctly performs.

```
vehicleService.getVehicles = function() {
               return  $http.get(url)
                    .then(function(result) {
                        $log.log('OKAY');
                        var returnObject = {};
                        returnObject.status = result.status;
                        returnObject.data = result.data;
                        $log.log(returnObject);
                        return returnObject;
                    })
                    .catch(function(result) {
                        $log.log('NOWAY');
                        var returnObject = {};
                        returnObject.status = result.status;
                        returnObject.errorList = result.data.modelState;
                        return returnObject;
                    });
```

My problem is when I try to return returnObject to the controller, I get the $http promise object instead of the returnObject.

I'm guessing it's because of the line **return $http.get(url)**, but shouldn't it first execute **then**, then pass returnObject?

EDIT: Forgot to change the title

Comment: You are returning the promise. When changed, the second line should read just ```$http.get(url)```. You do not need returns for callbacks

Comment: Which means that I can't use `then` to manipulate the promise, correct?

Comment: if you want to set values inside the promise resolve function you ve to return a promise from your service and use then inside the controller.... using $scope.returnObject = ......

Answer (score 0):

the $http is an async function, you may need

```
vehicleService.getVehicles = function(callback) { $http.get(url)
                .then(function(result) {
                    $log.log('OKAY');
                    var returnObject = {};
                    returnObject.status = result.status;
                    returnObject.data = result.data;
                    $log.log(returnObject);
                    callback(returnObject);
                })
                .catch(function(result) {
                    $log.log('NOWAY');
                    var returnObject = {};
                    returnObject.status = result.status;
                    returnObject.errorList = result.data.modelState;
                    callback(returnObject);
                });}
```

or you should use $scope.returnObject

Answer (score -1):

Replace code in your function with this:

```
            $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'url' }).
                success(function (result) {
                    $log.log('OKAY');
                    var returnObject = {};
                    returnObject.status = result.status;
                    returnObject.data = result.data;
                    $log.log(returnObject);
                    return returnObject;
                }).
                error(function (result) {
                    $log.log('NOWAY');
                });
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q if you look at the `The Promise API` you will see that `.then` and `.catch` are the proper way to handle promises